# How to fix error "Value of '256' is not valid for 'blue', 'blue' should be greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 255."

Tags: c#

This happens when the form loads, it sets the textbox's backcolor from user settings.

Here's when I set the color:

```
Main_Box.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(Properties.Settings.Default.TCP_BackgroundR, Properties.Settings.Default.TCP_BackgroundG, Properties.Settings.Default.TCP_BackgroundB);
```

Here's when I save the color:

```
byte
    gBackgroundR, gBackgroundG, gBackgroundB;

// Color dialog
gBackgroundR = CD_BG.Color.R;
gBackgroundG = CD_BG.Color.G;
gBackgroundB = CD_BG.Color.B;

Properties.Settings.Default.TCP_BackgroundR = gBackgroundR;
Properties.Settings.Default.TCP_BackgroundG = gBackgroundG;
Properties.Settings.Default.TCP_BackgroundB = gBackgroundB;
```

--

As I was writing this, I was trying to replicate the problem, but couldn't.. Its almost if its like a first time error only.. but just to be safe: Is the code I posted the correct way to save/load colors and setting them?

Comment: Have you initialized your values properly? The value 256 is out of scale for a `byte`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely had it hand written in the properties file a value of 256 for your color. Once you saved your setting from inside the program (or change what was hand written in the file) it overwrote it with a valid value and that is why the error is no longer happening.

As for the original problem: the valid range is 0-255, so when you passed in the value 256 in it errored out. Invalid data in your config files is something you need to look out for and handle in your code.

```
//Method 1 fix by setting a default value.
try
{
    Main_Box.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(Properties.Settings.Default.TCP_BackgroundR, Properties.Settings.Default.TCP_BackgroundG, Properties.Settings.Default.TCP_BackgroundB);
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    //If a invalid color was read in from the config file use white instead
    Main_Box.BackColor = Color.White;
}

//Method 2 fix by clamping values.
int red = Math.Min(Math.Max(Properties.Settings.Default.TCP_BackgroundR, 0), 255);
int green = Math.Min(Math.Max(Properties.Settings.Default.TCP_BackgroundG, 0), 255);
int blue = Math.Min(Math.Max(Properties.Settings.Default.TCP_BackgroundB, 0), 255);
Main_Box.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
```

Also your Properties file is using a byte to store the numbers, however `FromArgb` takes in a int within a restricted range. I would recommend matching what FromArgb takes in (a int) and using that in your properties file.

Comment: Thanks, going to use that!